# Tomcat requires long time to recognizes the start of spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a strange problem when deploying a `SpringBootApplication` packaged as `war` to a tomcat server.

Sometimes, the application startup is not recognized (or more precisely, it takes a very long time) by the tomcat server, although the application is successfully started. - If I say successfully I mean the application can perform backup jobs e.g. `cron` jobs, access its database and connect to 3rd party services via `SOAP`.

The problem when the tomcat server is not recognizing the startup is that the application's `REST` endpoints are not reachable and even worse, if I restarted the tomcat server when the application is placed in the webapps folder, the whole tomcat server would be frozen.

To be honest, I have no idea what might be the problem and where even to start looking.

I suspect, somehow, the custom `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` (see below) triggers this problem. But even if I set the pool-size to 1 this problem occurs.

Extracted from the log files showing the startup time:

1. normal startup:

   - application log file: `Started CrewAlertApplication in 17.358 seconds (JVM running for 58.215)`
   - catalina.out: `Deployment of web application archive [/srv/prod/cpappp/tomcat/webapps/crew-alert##1.2.1.war] has finished in [21.691] ms`
2. slow startup:

   - application logfile: `Started CrewAlertApplication in 25.161 seconds (JVM running for 75.633)`
   - catalina.out: `Deployment of web application archive [/srv/prod/cpappp/tomcat/webapps/crew-alert##1.2.1.war] has finished in [1.056.389] ms`

---

Here is some information concerning the environment:

Tomcat (runs on a `VMWare` machine, having 4 cores)

```
Server Version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.43
Server built:          Jan 28 2021 20:25:45 UTC
Server version number: 9.0.43.0
OS Name:               Linux
OS Version:            5.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
Architektur:           amd64
Java Home:             /srv/jdk-11.0.9+11
JVM Version:           11.0.9+11
JVM Hersteller:        Eclipse OpenJ9
```

The application itself is based on:

- SpringBoot: 2.0.5
- java: 11
- As mentioned above we use a custom `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("CrewAlertThreadPool");
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
    return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
}
```

---

The below images show the tomcat manager. The tomcat was started and the application then deployed (the other applications deployed on the tomcat all started successfully).
[image]

After some time the tomcat manager than shows the application as successfully started
[image]

---

**Update 1:**

As @AndyWilkinson pointet out the problem occurs in my `@EventListener` method which calls a `JpaRepository` method

```
List<ScheduledNotification> findByScheduledTimeBetween(ZonedDateTime from, ZonedDateTime to)
```

which is "translated" into

```
Hibernate: select scheduledn0_.id as id1_6_, scheduledn0_.alert_id as alert_id3_6_, scheduledn0_.scheduled_time as scheduled_time2_6_ 
    from scheduled_notification scheduledn0_
    where scheduledn0_.scheduled_time between ? and ?
```

Below an excerpt of the entity:

```
@Entity(name = "SCHEDULED_NOTIFICATION")
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "IDX_SCHED_NOTIF_SCHEDTIME", columnList = "SCHEDULED_TIME") })
public class ScheduledNotification extends AbstractId implements Comparable<ScheduledNotification> {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALERT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Alert alert;

    @Column(name = "SCHEDULED_TIME", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    @Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverterUtc.class)
    private ZonedDateTime scheduledTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "scheduledNotification", cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = EAGER)
    private Set<Leg> legs;
    ...
```

This call takes actually close to 18 minutes. Which is a little bit surprising because this table never contained more the 100 entries (and in this case returned 3 results).

```
2021-07-14 12:53:34.506  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] c.lalacomp.alert.CrewAlertApplication    : Started CrewAlertApplication in 26.577 seconds (JVM running for 108237.294)
2021-07-14 12:53:34.509  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] c.l.a.scheduler.NotificationExecutor     : ApplicationReadyEvent received.
2021-07-14 12:53:34.528 DEBUG [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] c.l.a.s.ScheduledNotificationServiceImpl : findImmediate() - Looking up schedules between: 2021-07-14T10:38:34Z[UTC] and 2021-07-14T11:08:34Z[UTC]
2021-07-14 12:53:34.572  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
...
2021-07-14 13:11:27.637 TRACE [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] c.l.a.s.ScheduledNotificationServiceImpl : We've found: ...
2021-07-14 13:11:27.639  INFO [] --- [Catalina-utility-3] c.l.a.scheduler.NotificationExecutor     : Adding 3 new ScheduledNotifications at startup.
...
```

et voilà the timestamps do match, the application is recognized as running:

```
14-Jul-2021 13:11:27.662 INFORMATION [Catalina-utility-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/srv/prod/cpappp/tomcat/webapps/crew-alert##1.2.2.war] has finished in [1.103.405] ms
```

So now I have to find out, why does this takes so long? Because other queries against the database (other tables) perform normally.

**Update 2:**

If I run a similar `sql` statement on the console directly the runtime is absolutly fine.

```
select * from scheduled_notification sn
    join leg l on sn.id = l.SCHEDULED_NOTIFICATION_ID
    join alert a on sn.ALERT_ID = a.id
    where scheduled_time between SYSTIMESTAMP and SYSTIMESTAMP + 2 /24;

Fetched 30 rows in 0.015 secs
```

I'm also wondering why the `Hibernate` statement from above (Update 1) does not include the "join relations".

Comment: Can you take a thread dump when the application appears to have started but Tomcat hasn’t noticed?

Comment: thx @AndyWilkinson, you can find the dump here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb8edzl976wehnd/javacore.20210714.125356.1049494.0002.txt?dl=0

Comment: It's the `Catalina-utility-3` thread that is deploying the application. The thread dump shows that your application has a listener for the `ApplicationReadyEvent`. This listener has called some code that's using Hibernate to talk to your Oracle DB and that's what it's doing at the time that the thread dump was taken. It's impossible to tell from a single dump if this is taking a long time, but that's where I would start investigating. Perhaps you could enable some Hibernate or Oracle JDBC driver logging to get a feel for how long things are taking when talking to the DB.

Comment: Correct, the `@EventListener` method is taking that much time - or more precisely the call to the `JpaRepository` method `findByScheduledTimeBetween(ZonedDateTime from, ZonedDateTime to)` - which is a little bit surprising, because this table contains only up to max. 100 entries. The method returns after nearly 18 minutes. I will updated the question with an excert from the logfile.

Answer (score 1):

As @AndyWilkinson pointed out, the problem was in the `ApplicationReadyEvent`.  In the method connected to this event I fetch data from the DB and this took a very long time due some expensive relations.

I've updated the Entity and simplified some of these relationships. Now the method performs as expected.

Big thanks and all the credit to Andy!